# Angularjs POST to PHP printing blank values in email and console

Tags: php, angularjs, email, post

I'm trying to submit values from angularjs to a php page, then have the php page send the values to an email. The problem is that the variables sent to the email are printing blank. When in my IDE, the variables will dump to the log properly, but when the same action is performed on a site on the internet (tried on two separate websites), the variables intended to be printed into the email do not print to the log on a dump.

https://github.com/Cameron64/BCIS4610

PHP code:

```
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && strpos($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'], 'application/json') === 0 ) {
    $postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $_POST = json_decode($postdata, true);
    $_REQUEST = array_merge($_REQUEST, $_POST);
}


//$data['message'] = $_POST['customer'];
$data = json_decode($_POST['customer']);
//var_dump($data);
$basket = array();
$basketQuantities = array();
$email = $data->email;
$phone = $data->num;
$company = $data->restaurant;
$products = $data->product;
$quantities = $data->quantities;
$comments = $data->comments;
$counter = 0;

//var_dump($_POST['customer']);

for($i=0; $i<= sizeof($products,0)-1; $i++){
    array_push($basket, $data->product[$i]->id);
}

for($i=0; $i<= sizeof($products,0)-1; $i++){
    if($data->quantities[$i] != null)
    {$basketQuantities[$i]=$data->quantities[$i];
    }
    else{
        array_push($basketQuantities[$i], "1");
    };
}



  $final = "";
    $final .= "Email: " . $email . "\n"
    .         "Company Name: ". $company . "\n"
        .     "Phone Number: ". $phone . "\n".
    "They ordered: \n";
    for($i=0; $i <= sizeof($products,0)-1; $i++){

        $final .= $basket[$i] . "\t" . $basketQuantities[$i] . "\n";
    }
    if($comments != null){
        $final .= "They also left a comment with their order:" . "\n" . wordwrap($comments);
    }




$mailTo = "myemail@ymail.com";
$mailSubject = "New Order";

var_dump($final);

if($counter < 1){
    mail($mailTo,$mailSubject,$final);
    $counter++;
}
```

AngularJS code

```
    this.basket =[];
        this.customer ={};
        this.customer.email = "";
        this.customer.num = "";
        this.customer.restaurant = "";
        this.customer.product=[];
        this.customer.quantities=[];
        this.customer.comments= "";


this.formSubmit = function(){


            if(document.getElementById('email').checkValidity() && document.getElementById('tel').checkValidity()
                && document.getElementById('name').checkValidity()){

                lol = this;
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/SendOrder.php',
                    data: $.param({'customer' : JSON.stringify(lol.customer)}),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).
                    success(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        window.location = "invoice.html";
                    })
            }

            };
```

The values are populated via an nd-model in for form. I don't believe it is being submitted as a form, don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here? No one will go digging through that repo to find it.

Comment: No problem, I was it a bit of a hurry. Very frustrated with this problem. I'm told that the PHP looks fine, so I think the angular might be the issue